# "Floating" android application GUI

Tags: java, android, user-interface

I am well aware that the term "Floating" is probably not valid but it was the only word that came to mind to describe what I am trying to do.

So,I am trying to develop a widget-like application that calculates remaining Megabytes for 3G. The thing is that I want easy access to it and would like to have it remain always on top. While I have been able to handle most of it I am having a hard time implementing the following idea.

I want the application to always keep a small icon on screen,which will display a number,the amount of remaining Megabytes. The idea is that this icon will be small and will always remain on screen and at the same time I will be able to use the other applications in the background.

An example of a similar application would be the facebook messenger app which remains almost always on screen without interfering with the other apps the user might run at the same time.

I have looked over several websites and I could not find any idea on how to make something like that,so I am turning to you for assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're wanting to do is to create a view (that doesn't take up the entire screen) and add it directly to the WindowManager, instead of what apps normally do, which is create an activity (the content view of an activity is also added to the WindowManager, but that is done for you automatically).

In the layout parameters of your view (see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html) you'd choose an appropriate type of window, e.g. `TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY` or  `TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT`. That will cause your view to appear on top of other windows. Beware that some types of windows require permissions that you need to declare in the manifest, and they have different restrictions. It may take some experimentation to determine the right window type!

Use the hierarchy viewer to take a look at the Facebook Messenger app when it's running - you'll notice it has a window that 'higher' up, which is what the window types mentioned above achieve.

This should give you enough pointers to get you going.

Comment: Many many thanks Theo. You cannot imagine how much this has troubled me.